# BindParam() not working properly

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam

In my DB class I have a method `query()` which takes the SQL statement and the parameters as arguments and runs them in the database.

```
    // the parameters are the sql statement and the values, returns the the current object
    // the result set object can be accessed by using the results() method

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

        $this->_error = false;  // initially the error is set to false

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {

            // if the parameters are set, bind it with the statement
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param => $value) {
                    $this->_query->bindParam($param, $value);
                }
            }

            // if the query is successfully executed save the resultset object to the $_results property
            // and store the total row count in $_count
            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;

    }
```

and this is how I am calling the method

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND id = :id ", array(':username' => 'sayantan94', ':id' => 1));
```

But when I `print_r()` the result set, I am getting an empty array. But if I do this

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", array(':username' => 'sayantan94'));
```

or this

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id ", array(':id' => 1));
```

I am getting proper result. What is wrong with my code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from what is said in the other answer, most of your code is either useless or harmful. In fact, you need only these few lines

```
public function query($sql, $params = array())
{
    $query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query; 
}
```

It will do everything your function does, but without that much code and without nasty side effects. Imagine you will run a nested query in a loop. What become your $this->_results variable after the second query execution? In such a function **there should be no class variables related to a particular query.**

Besides,

- no need to check the prepare result manually - PDO will throw an **exception** by itself
- no need for the `_error` variable as it's pretty useless, while PDO's own exception is way more useful and informative
- no need to bind in a loop - `execute()` can bind all parameters at once
- no need to test `$params` array - `execute()` will accept an empty array as well.
- no need to return `fetchAll()` restult - you can always do it later, by chaining it like this `$data = $db->query($sql, $params)->fetchAll();`
- no need for `rowCount()` - you can always just count the array returned from fetchAll()

Comment: @SayantanDas please check my article for the in-depth explanations of some bad practices you were using, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check that article.

Answer (score 1):

You foreach is false, $value by value, because bindParam needs &$variable, Make a reference, try this:

```
if(count($params)) {
   foreach($params as $param => &$value) {
       $this->_query->bindParam($param, $value);
   }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: i am getting this error `Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based in D:\xampp\htdocs\oop\classes\DB.php on line 50`